# To get which object requested this window to show

Tags: c#, winforms, show, sender

I want to create a window which shows a graphic.
There are 4 menu items within a menustrip. When clicking on the menu item the  DetailsGraph window will be appear. But in this form I want to get the name of which menu item was clicked to open this form. So, I will show the precise graph on the my form.

```
    private void menuItemTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new GraphOneWindow()).Show();
    }

    private void menuItemConductivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new GraphOneWindow()).Show();
    }
```

In which function can I get the sender object inside `GraphOneWindow.cs` ?

Comment: Give the form constructor an argument.

Comment: I felt myself as a stupid :DDDD Absolutely you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass sender to forms constructor:

```
public class GraphOneWindow:Form
{
   public GraphOneWindow(object sender)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //cast and use sender here
   }
}

private void menuItemTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   (new GraphOneWindow(sender)).Show();
}
```